# How to append names from two separate lists to append and merge to one list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I am trying to append names to an empty list that has an empty string and an empty list. 
I want to iterate using a for loop or a loop that will be able to through the friendsNum list and in the string parenthesis will insert a random name from peoplenames list which is i[0] then after two random names from the list called friendnames in the empty list which will be i[1] after the string, and to continue until the last list.

```
    import random 
    friendsNum = [("",[]),("",[]),("",[]),("",[])]
    peopleNames = ["Alvin","Danny","Maria","Lauren"]
    friendNames = ("john","matt","will","mario","wilma","shannon","mary","jordan") 

    newList = friendsNum
    tempName = ()
    temp = ()
    for i in friendsNum:
        tempName = random.sample(peopleNames,1)
        temp = random.sample(friendNames,2)
        newList = i[0].append(tempName)
        newList = i[1].append(temp)
```

After this for loop iterates, it will look like this.

```
    friendsNum = [("Johnny",["john","matt"]),
                  ("Zach",["wilma","shannon"]),
                  ("Dawn",["mary","jordan"]),
                  ("Max",["will","john"])]
```

I keep getting a error of not being able to append a string object from the lines

```
 newList = i[0].append(tempName)
 newList = i[1].append(temp)
```

Am I approaching this wrong as for the loop I should be using?

The error message below

```
    newList = i[0].append(tempName)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: @Imm, please include the error message you're seeing.

Comment: @Todd just put at the bottom, I hope my question is clear for what I am trying to do. I'm not sure if it's possible what I am trying to do.

Comment: just removing the string quotes from the `friendsNum` list and then appending should work, as you can't append something to an empty string unless it's a `join()`.

Comment: the line `i[0].append(tempName)` is accessing the first member of a tuple `("", [])` which is a string. You can't change that string - tuple's are immutable. You can't reassign another object to a placement in a tuple. That's the first problem. The second is that strings also being immutable don't support `append()` like a list does. @Imm - maybe you want to use lists in place of your tuples (they can be updated) and replace the empty string with the tempName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first element is empty string in friendsnum so you can not use append operation on string. Also, you cant assign values in a tuple as its immutable.

```
    import random 
    friendsNum = [("",[]),("",[]),("",[]),("",[])]
    peopleNames = ["Alvin","Danny","Maria","Lauren"]
    friendNames = ("john","matt","will","mario","wilma","shannon","mary","jordan") 

    newList = []
    tempName = ()
    temp = ()
    for i in friendsNum:
        tempName = random.sample(peopleNames,1)
        temp = random.sample(friendNames,2)
        i = list(i)
        i[0] = (tempName[0])
        i[1] = (temp)
        newList.append(tuple(i))
```

use above updated code, here is sample output

```
[('Danny', ['shannon', 'will']),
 ('Alvin', ['jordan', 'john']),
 ('Maria', ['mary', 'will']),
 ('Alvin', ['wilma', 'mary'])]
```

Comment: maybe you can mention how this deals with the tuples in friendsNum for the poster @Mohitsharma

Answer (score 2):

Number of problems:

- `i[0].append(tempName)`: `i[0]` is a `str` and thus won't have `append`. Besides, you can't directly modify it since it is already in a tuple and it's immutable.
- `i[1].append(temp)`: since `temp` is a list, `i[1].append(temp)` will make it a nested list. You need `extend`
- Since both `append` and `extend` are inplace operation, `newList` is effectively doing nothing.

Instead, try one-liner with list comprehension:

```
[(random.choice(peopleNames), random.sample(friendNames,2)) for i in range(len(peopleNames))]
```

Output:

```
[('Danny', ['shannon', 'john']),
 ('Maria', ['mary', 'shannon']),
 ('Lauren', ['matt', 'wilma']),
 ('Alvin', ['will', 'mario'])]
```